# Combine Dazing Spell with Create Pit

Tags: pathfinder-1e, metamagic

The Metamagic Feat Dazing Spell says:

> When a creature takes damage from this spell, they become dazed...

If I create a pit and the enemy falls into it will it be dazed if I have casted it 3 levels higher using Dazing Spell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No

[Dazing Spell](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Dazing%20Spell) says:

> When a creature takes damage from this spell, they become dazed for a
> number of rounds equal to the original level of the spell. […] Spells
> that do not inflict damage do not benefit from this feat.

while [Create Pit](https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Create%20Pit) says:

> Creatures who fall into the pit take falling damage as normal.

Thus, the spell itself does not deal any damage to creatures, they merely take falling damage as normal. Just like you wouldn't deal falling damage with a spell that merely pushes someone over the edge of a cliff.

However, other pit spells like *Spiked Pit* and *Acid Pit* do deal their own piercing/acid spell damage and can therefore be used with Dazing Spell.